# Core Location + allow to use your current Location?

Tags: iphone, core-location

In my application corelocation manager updates the current location more than once by calling "startUpdatingLocation" method.

When i run the application on device it behaves differently on different devices.

On iPod touch with iOS 3.0 it asks "Application would like to use your current location" every time i call [locationManager startUpdatingLocation]; till i don't press allow button in alert view.

But on other device iPhone3G with iOS 4.0.2 it does not show alert "application would like to use your current location" every time. It asks for only once. if i select "DontAllow" then also it does not ask again when i call [locationManager startUpdatingLocation]; again where in case of iPod it does.

Also in simulator with iOS 4.0.2 it ask every time till you don't select "allow" in alert view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confirmation prompt will be shown three times by the OS. If the user says "OK" all three times, the OS figures they don't need to be asked again. If the user says "No" to any of them, they also won't be asked again. You can control access at a per-application level by going into Settings > General > Location Services.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have observed in my ipod touch(3.0-iOS) it asks every time, when i select "don't allow". But in other devices this is not the case, it's behaving as you mentioned. What could be the reason for that? Could that be a iOS version problem? Any document/resource for this issue would be great. Thanks once again.

Comment: Do you know of a way to reset iOS so that it starts showing the alert view for the three times again? I want to do it for testing...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can reset the IOS Simulator by going to IOS Simulator >> Reset Contents and Settings.

Alternatively on the i-phone simply delete the application and reinstall, that should clear all settings for it as well.